# Changing cell range to cover all data in column

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro in my excel sheet

The aim of the macro is to copy the cells in one column, one by one (L1,L2...), into a specific cell (A1). then after the calculations are done, copy the value from another cell E2, to the column next to L, meaning to M1, M2...

i couldn't know how to loop these steps to all the cells in the column.

```
Sub Checking_Frequences()
'
' Checking_Frequences Macro
'

'
    Range("L1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("E2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("M1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("L2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("E2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("M2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

is there a way to add a delay, so that excel finish calculations before copying the result from E2?

any advice?

regards

Comment: Why dont you fill an array with results isntead of working through copy/pasting differenct cells one after the other? Or fill down a formula in `M1` to your last used row.  What specific calculations take place in `E2`?

Comment: The concept of feeding values to Excel to do calculations with is wrong. You can read any number of values from a worksheet (in whichever way you prefer), do whatever calculations you want to do with them in VBA, and write the result to any cell in the workbook. It's VBA that should do the calculations. You can even let it use worksheet functions, if you want.

Comment: @JvdV you are both right, but i don't know how to do that...

Comment: @Variatus you are both right, but i don't know how to do that...

Answer (score 1):

Your workbook can do with a little organisational upgrading. I may not have done it the way you best like but I think the code below will let you take a big step forward. Install it in a standard code module and run only the procedure *WriteArrays*. Take time to understand how it works first.

```
Sub WriteArrays()
    ' 043

    ' number of results wanted from each Base
    Const Iterations As Integer = 5     ' adjust to suit
    Const TgtTab As String = "Sheet3"   ' Output tab (change to suit)
    Const TgtRow As Long = 2            ' modify to suit
    Const TgtClm As Long = 4            ' first output column (modify to suit)

    Dim Src         As Variant          ' array of source Base numbers
    Dim R           As Long             ' SrcRng row counter
    Dim WsTgt       As Worksheet        ' Target worksheet (for output)
    Dim Arr         As Variant          ' value to write to sheet
    Dim Operand     As Double           ' calculated by a formula
    Dim i           As Long             ' loop counter

    Operand = 2 ^ (1 / 12)              ' = 1.0594630943593 (adjust to suit)

    With Worksheets("Frequencies")
        ' set the range L1:L(last used row) - modify to suit
        ' read all values into an array
        Src = .Range(.Cells(1, "L"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp)).Value
    End With
    Set WsTgt = Worksheets(TgtTab)

    For R = LBound(Src) To UBound(Src)
        Arr = BaseArray(Src(R, 1), Operand, Iterations)
        With WsTgt.Cells(TgtRow, TgtClm - 1 + R).Resize(UBound(Arr))
            .Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)
            .NumberFormat = "0.00"
        End With
'        If R = 5 Then Exit For
    Next R
End Sub

Private Function BaseArray(ByVal Base As Double, _
                           ByVal Operand As Double, _
                           ByVal Iterations As Integer) As Variant
    ' 043

    Dim Fun         As Variant          ' function return value
    Dim i           As Integer

    ReDim Fun(1 To Iterations)
    For i = LBound(Fun) To UBound(Fun)
        Fun(i) = Base
        Base = Round(Base * Operand, 2)
    Next i
    BaseArray = Fun
End Function
```

There are 4 constants at the top of the code which you will have to set. The last 3 deal with the output. You asked for output in column M on the same sheet. But this code will add 235 columns. So I thought it better to start a new sheet. You can easily run the code multiple times with different parameters and output the results on different sheets. But they must exist before the code is run.

`Const Iterations` specifies how many rows there will be in each column. You seem to want 50. I tested with only 5. Modify this constant to suit your needs.

A little further down there is the `Operand` which is the formula taken from your cell C1. It can be changed.

Of course, the tab *Frequencies* must exist and it must have numbers in column L. You can start from row 2 instead of 1. But if you want to limit the output you may like to avail yourself of the method I used, here: `If R = 5 Then Exit For` (at the end of the Next ../.. For loop). It just curtails the loop after 5 numbers from the list, if you enable the line by removing the leading apostrophe.

I wish you the best of luck with your venture :-)

Comment: I'm not hiding anything. I want to move along the column one cell after the other.... copy the values from L column to cell A1, once the calculations are done in the excel sheet, i want to copy the result from E2 to the cell beside the one used in L column (M column)... got me? shall i share the file?

Comment: @Saher Again, change your concept! Don't plan on doing any calculation ins Excel. It must be done in VBA. Above I have shown you how to read a value from the sheet into VBA. I also showed you how to paste a value from VBA into the worksheet. All you got to do is copy what I wrote. Maybe you are indeed not hiding the formula in E2 but you aren't showing it, either. Had you disclosed it you would have had an answer by now because, as you probably realize, whatever happens in E2 is key to your question. Yes, by all means, share the file.

Comment: I guess you are right, calculations must be done in VBA. but they are so many calculations...i feel lost to be honest.
here is the file:
 https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zcvGmmlbWR6AOKQv4ZTmfQjwJXbPMBIm?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't find any calculation in which your sheet uses the value value in A1. BTW, the counts in D2:D4 include the values in C2:C4 which are different from C5:C112

Comment: column B, uses the value in A1, to calculate all the musical frequencies.
it starts from the cell **B62**, calculations moves above it and below it gradually to calculate all the frequencies for all the notes.
after at. the digital root is calculated for the results, to how often i get 3,6 &9. that is why i count them.
I use the values in L column to be used in A1. i get these values from the other sheet **Sacred**, which aims to find the frequencies that has 3.6 & 9 as digital root.
the aim of this work, is to find one frequency that makes all the digital roots 3,6 or 9. got me? @Variatus

Comment: hello? i guess no one is interested?

Comment: @Saher Al-Sous Your comment is unexpected. It looks like you didn't see the code I posted which, if it isn't the solution you were seeking should be very near to it and, in any case, not a sign of no interest even if it completely fails. Please take another look at my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't see that. i was looking straight at the end of the page before checking the items above.. i will work on that and hopefully i can do it... thank you